# GROUP_CONCAT equivalent in Django

Tags: mysql, django, group-concat

Say I have the following table called `fruits`:

```
id | type   | name
-----------------
 0 | apple  | fuji
 1 | apple  | mac
 2 | orange | navel
```

My goal is to ultimately come up with a count of the different `types` and a comma-delimited list of the `names`:

```
apple, 2, "fuji,mac"
orange, 1, "navel"
```

This can be easily done with `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL but I'm having trouble with the Django equivalent.  This is what I have so far but I am missing the `GROUP_CONCAT` stuff:

```
query_set = Fruits.objects.values('type').annotate(count=Count('type')).order_by('-count')
```

I would like to avoid using raw SQL queries if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django ORM does not support this; if you don't want to use raw SQL then you'll need to [group and join](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: A colleague of mine maintains an open source project that exposes mysql specific functions like GROUP_CONCAT in django. Take a look https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/

Comment: Just note that for Postgres we have django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.StringAgg.

Answer (score 59):

You can create your own Aggregate Function ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions#django.db.models.Aggregate))

```py
from django.db.models import Aggregate

class Concat(Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
        super(Concat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            output_field=CharField(),
            **extra)
```

and use it simply as:

```py
query_set = Fruits.objects.values('type').annotate(count=Count('type'),
                       name = Concat('name')).order_by('-count')
```

I am using django 1.8 and mysql 4.0.3

Comment: NOTICE that Django (>=1.8) provides [`Database functions`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40478702/2714931)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there is also: `django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.StringAgg` in case you want the same in Postgres

Comment: This function is also present in `django-mysql`: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html?highlight=GroupConcat#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat

Comment: For django 2.2 I needed to add `allow_distinct = True` to Concat class

Comment: @LorenzoPeña That is the only thing which worked amongst the jungle of Group Concat articles and answers. You should add that as an answer `StringAgg(fieldname, delimiter)`

Comment: A word of caution: MySQL will truncate GROUP_CONCAT result to 1024 characters, by default - I've spent some time figuring out why I was getting non-existent ids. You can set group_concat_max_len, example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475140/include-multiple-statements-in-djangos-raw-queries

Comment: Note: if someone faces not defined issue of `CharField` in line `output_field=CharField(),` then you may just replace `from django.db.models import Aggregate` to  `from django.db.models import Aggregate, CharField`

Answer (score 22):

NOTICE that Django (>=1.8) provides [`Database functions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/) support.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat

Here is an enhanced version of `Shashank Singla`

```py
from django.db.models import Aggregate, CharField

class GroupConcat(Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s%(ordering)s%(separator)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, ordering=None, separator=',', **extra):
        super(GroupConcat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            ordering=' ORDER BY %s' % ordering if ordering is not None else '',
            separator=' SEPARATOR "%s"' % separator,
            output_field=CharField(),
            **extra
        )
```

Usage:

```py
LogModel.objects.values('level', 'info').annotate(
    count=Count(1), time=GroupConcat('time', ordering='time DESC', separator=' | ')
).order_by('-time', '-count')
```

Comment: It doesn;t work for me.
Another fine example:
https://gist.github.com/ludoo/ca6ed07e5c8017272701

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin this works well in my project using Django 1.10.x

Comment: Works well in Django 1.11.x. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use `GroupConcat` from the Django-MySQL package (
https://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat ) which I maintain. With it you can do it simply like:

```
>>> from django_mysql.models import GroupConcat
>>> Fruits.objects.annotate(
...     count=Count('type'),
...     name_list=GroupConcat('name'),
... ).order_by('-count').values('type', 'count', 'name_list')
[{'type': 'apple', 'count': 2, 'name_list': 'fuji,mac'},
 {'type': 'orange', 'count': 1, 'name_list': 'navel'}]
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I am somehow confused. May be am missing something. So how does the GroupConcat know that it will concatenate values of field 'name' ? As I don't see you indicating the field 'name' anywhere in the query, and yet  we are concatenating values in field 'name'

Comment: Great! Your answer was helpful. I will give you a vote. :) @adam-chainz

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use `ArrayAgg` to aggregate all of the values into an array.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind doing this in your template the Django template tag [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) accomplishes this

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 1.8 you can use [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

```
query_set = Fruits.objects.values('type').annotate(
    count=Count('type'),
    name=Func(F('name'), 'GROUP_BY')
).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar Aggregate Function for PostgreSQL in case someone needs:

```
from django.db.models import Aggregate, CharField

class GroupConcat(Aggregate):
    function = "STRING_AGG"
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s::text, %(separator)s%(ordering)s)"

    def __init__(self, expression, ordering=None, separator=',', **extra):
        super().__init__(
            expression,
            ordering=" ORDER BY %s" % ordering if ordering is not None else "",
            separator="'%s'" % separator,
            output_field=CharField(),
            **extra
        )

queryset = Fruits.objects.values('type').annotate(
    count=Count('type'),
    name=GroupConcat('name')
).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not supported by Django ORM, but you can build your own aggregator.

It's actually pretty straightforward, here is a link to a how-to that does just that, with `GROUP_CONCAT` for SQLite: http://harkablog.com/inside-the-django-orm-aggregates.html

Note however, that it might be necessary to handle different SQL dialects separately. For example, the [SQLite docs say about `group_concat`](http://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary

While [MySQL allows you to specify the order](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

I guess that may be a reason why `GROUP_CONCAT` it's not implemented in Django at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @WeizhongTu, Notice that you can not use the keyword *SEPARATOR* with SQLITE. In cases where you are using MySQL and SQLite for your tests, you can write :

```
class GroupConcat(Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    separator = ','

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, ordering=None, **extra):
        super(GroupConcat, self).__init__(expression,
                                          distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
                                          ordering=' ORDER BY %s' % ordering if ordering is not None else '',
                                          output_field=CharField(),
                                          **extra)

    def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection, separator=separator):
        return super().as_sql(compiler,
                              connection,
                              template='%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s%(ordering)s%(separator)s)',
                              separator=' SEPARATOR \'%s\'' % separator)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, **extra):
        return super().as_sql(compiler,
                              connection,
                              template='%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s%(ordering)s)',
                              **extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say a word of caution if you go with any of the proposed solutions for MySQL: by default, MySQL will truncate GROUP_CONCAT result to 1024 characters. I've spent some time figuring out why I was getting non-existent ids (they were truncated existent ids).

You can avoid the limitation by setting group_concat_max_len in Django settings. An example is here: [Include multiple statements in Django's raw queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475140/include-multiple-statements-in-djangos-raw-queries)

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way of working in Django ORM

```
f1 = Fruits.objects.values('type').annotate(count = Count('type'),namelist= GroupConcat('namelist')).distinct()
```