# Group concat using django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I need to fire following query using ORM

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( af.name ) AS item, ac.name AS categories
FROM admin_fooditem af
JOIN admin_category ac ON ( ac.id = af.category_id ) 
GROUP BY ac.id
```

The output is as below

```
item                              Categories

Tuborg beer                       Beverages
Mutter Paneer,Palak Paneer        Vegeterian entries
Coke,Fanta                        Soft drinks
```

The original tables are

admin_category

```
        id  name    
        11  Softdrinks
        5   Vegeterian Entry
        2   Beverages
```

admin_fooditem

```
        id  name         category_id
        1   Palak Paneer    5
        2   Mutter Paneer   5
        5   Tuborg beer     2
        6   Coke            11
        7   Fanta           11
```

I have used simple join `query(FoodItem.objects.select_related('Category').all())` and then `regroup` tag in template , but now I need json output of the above sql, I am  clueless so I am using raw sql for now

Thanks!

Comment: please have a look on edited question , i have explained the scenario, any help will be appreciated

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10340684

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django 1.4, you can call `prefetch_related()` on your Categories QuerySet and it would probably be slightly less efficient, as @ColeMaclean pointed out.

If you are using older django version and these queries will be executed frequently, stick with raw SQL. The only other way, using `extra()` on QuerySet won't work, as you need custom group by statement (I actually started writing an answer that suggested using `extra()` but found out it can't add GROUP BY parameters).

Without `prefetch_related()` the code by Cole will hit database on each category. It's easy to  execute a few hundred database queries per page by using code like this in production.

Comment: Ooh, good catch, forgot to add prefetch_related(). That's important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) if you want in Django, but I think in this case you should probably just use the ORM. It's (very slightly) less efficient but much easier to work with.

E.g, just do something like (untested, may not work):

```
json_dict = {}
for category in Category.objects.all():
    json_dict.update({
        'category': category.name,
        'items': ','.join(category.items.values_list('name', flat=True)),
    })
```

Then JSON encode the result.