# Include multiple statements in Django's raw queries

Tags: django, django-mysql

Is there any way we can include multiple statements inside on raw queries.

My use case would be I need to run

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len=100000;
```

before the select statement.

## Update

For my specific problem, I solved by adding a init_command for the MySQL configuration in my settings.py.

```
    "OPTIONS": {
        "init_command": "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;"
    }
```

However, I am still looking for solutions directly solved my initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not support multiple statements in a QuerySet. Anyway for variables such as `group_concat_max_len`, you are much better putting them in `init_command`, or if you have enough control on your database server, setting them globally as an admin account and storing the value in `my.cnf`.