# Using GROUP_CONCAT with other annotations in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I use an annotation which counts upvotes/downvotes while returning a list of articles:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
        upvotes_count=models.Sum(
            models.Case(
                models.When(likes__like_state=1, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=models.IntegerField()
            )
        )
    ).annotate(
        downvotes_count=models.Sum(
            models.Case(
                models.When(likes__like_state=-1, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=models.IntegerField()
            ))
    )
```

But each article also has a few categories as ManyToMany related field and I needed to return those categories comma-separated, so I wrote this function:

```
class GroupConcat(models.Aggregate):

    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = "%(function)s(%(distinct)s %(expressions)s %(separator)s)"

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, separator=', ', **extra):
        super(GroupConcat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT' if distinct else '',
            separator="SEPARATOR '%s'" % separator,
            output_field=models.CharField(),
            **extra
        )
```

And added it to my annotation:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(category=GroupConcat('categories__name'))
```

It works fine but `upvotes_count` and `downvotes_count` went crazy and started to multiply(!) results by amount of categories.

So the question is: "Is there a way to use GROUP_CONCAT in Django without breaking down SUM annotations?"

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017535, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10340684

Answer (score 0):

Very nice solution.
But to operate with group by field you should use order_by statement.
for example:

> Store.objects.all().values('value').order_by('value').annotate(stores=GroupConcat('id'))

would generate sql statement

> SELECT `store`.`value`, GROUP_CONCAT(`store`.`id` SEPARATOR ",") AS
> `stores` FROM `store` WHERE `store`.`value` > 0 GROUP BY
> `store`.`value` ORDER BY `store`.`value` ASC

and result would be
value, stores
1   "16,27"

Without order_by it would be like this:

> SELECT `store`.`value`, GROUP_CONCAT(`store`.`id` SEPARATOR ",") AS
> `stores` FROM `store` WHERE `store`.`value` > 0 GROUP BY `store`.`id`
> ORDER BY `store`.`value` ASC

and result would be
value, stores
1   16
2   27

Comment: Pay attention what is default ordering in Model class definition.