# Django aggregate by split string

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I would like to aggregate by a substring of one of my fields.

models.py

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(db_column='SYMBOL', max_length=16)
    number = models.IntegerField(db_column='NUMBER')
```

Where symbol will be something like;

```
'symbol': 'foo.bar', 'number':5
'symbol': 'foo.foo', 'number':10
'symbol': 'some.water', 'number':1
'symbol': 'some.milk', 'number':1
```

What I would like is to aggregate by;

```
symbol.split('.')[0]
```

With the end result being something like;

```
'symbol': 'foo', 'number': 15
'symbol': 'some', 'number': 2
```

I've looked at the `annotate` and `aggregate` documentation but I am struggling with this. Thanks.

Comment: Check the answer from Shashank Singla `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340684/group-concat-equivalent-in-django`

Comment: Thanks, I've solved the problem using a combination of this comment and the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={'symbol': 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(symbol, ".")'})?
```

Comment: thanks, this works to correctly identify the substring but I am unable to use `aggregate` on a parameter introduced by `extra`