# Defining custom delimiter for Django GROUP_CONCAT simulator

Tags: python, django

```
class Concat(Aggregate):
    # supports COUNT(distinct field)
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
        super(Concat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            output_field=CharField(),
            **extra)
```

I have come across a [splendid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340684/group-concat-equivalent-in-django) in Stackoverflow which provided a Django solution to simulate MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`. And now I am wondering how to set a delimiter for it in Django. I tried many possible options, among them `'%(function)s(%(distinct)s% ", "(expressions)s)'`, but none of my attemps were successful. Any ideas  ?

Comment: Why would you need delimeter here?

Comment: In fact, I would like to insert a newline as delimiter, because I have a long line in my HTML table resulting in rows overlapping